# BackgroundMediaPlayer share data with Foreground in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, share, background-audio

I need to share an audio file which is opened (read-only) from foreground task (UI), and is being played by the BackgroundMediaPlayer task in Windows Phone 8.1.

While it is being played in the background, I also need to access the same file from the foreground UI, again as read-only to retrieve its byte content.

What is the best way to achieve it? 
Is storing it to IsolatedStorage an option?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve? As in do you want to pass the audio file path from foreground to background or vice verse? How exactly do you want to modify the file from the foreground while it's being played by the background agent? If you're simply trying to communicate between the two then the `BackgroundMediaPlayer` has `SendMessageToForeground` and `SendMessageToBackground` methods and also their corresponding events.

Comment: In the background, I need to initiate the audio file playback by passing the file path.


In the foreground, I want to open the file from the same path (as read-only) to analyze its byte content.